# CSS :first-of-type not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I thought :first-of-type will effect the first-of-type which in my case is

```
<div class="box">I am the first box in div.center...</div>
```

If I remove the  `<div class="top">` the CSS works and adds the green-top-border.

But I need `<div class="top">`, so why is it not working if `<div class="top">` is there?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChHXh/1/)

```
<div class="main-wrap">
    <div class="center">
        <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
        <div class="top">XXX XXX XXXX</div>
        <div class="box">I am the first box in div.center. Why no top border?</div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.box {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    margin:10px 0;
    background-color:orange;
}

.main-wrap .center div.box:first-of-type {
    border-top:4px solid green;
}
.box {
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:4px solid green;
}
```

Comment: `first-of-type` operates at the "type" (element name) level - that is, you can select the first `div` in a container; not the selector level - it won't choose the first `div` with a specific class, ID, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you have `div.top` there, that becomes the first `div` element within its parent. `:first-of-type` only looks at the type of element; `div.box:first-of-type` really means select `div:first-of-type` only when it has the class `.box`, and not the first `div.box`.

To reach the first `div.box`, use an adjacent sibling selector:

```
.main-wrap .center div.top + div.box {
    border-top:4px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what I have done wrong and was just about to ask how to get the right result then... Thank you for this exact explanation

Answer (score 2):

The CSS declaration is over-qualified. If this design pattern repeats through out the site then using the following sibling selector is just as good and cleaner:

```
.top + .box {
    border-top: 4px solid green;
}
```

The browser looks at the declaration from right to left, so will scan for all the `.box` classes and then scan for the `.box` classes that are associated `.top`. By adding the additional classes, the browser is forced to re-scan 2 more times before applying the declaration styles.